# Phonegap with Android XML

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-plugins, android-applicationinfo

I'm working on a android application

I would like to create a  application for android using phone gap.

Is this possible? can I create a front end design in Android XML and back end controller functions in phonegap and make it an app in android studio  ?

Any thoughts / experiences?

Comment: what do you mean by back end? android apps and phonegap apps are usually considered "front end"

Comment: I mean the back end as controller function and front end as UI design

Comment: well, it could be possible, the phonegap webview can execute java code using plugins, and native components (your UI) can call javascript functions, you just need to hide (not delete) the phonegap webview (that is the default UI on phonegap apps) and put your native android UI with calls to webview.loadUrl("javascript:theJSFunctionYouWantToCall();");

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use cordova/phone gap to develop mobile apps. But these framework uses HTML5/css/JS technologies to do so. Sn android.xml would not work. You need to create your UI using HTML+CSS and code your business lodic in JS.